# Disable logging in neo4j

Tags: logging, neo4j

Is there a way to disable logging for neo4j?
I've looked into and tweaked the configurations in logging.properties, but without success.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Logs provide very useful information for all kind of trouble.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Ok, I'll rephrase my question to disable or redirect. The log file has other information I would like to see, but it is getting overshadowed by the stuff neo4j is writing.

Answer (score 0):

neo4j uses [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

The file you need to edit is `logback.xml`